# Dúvida For i Range Python

Tags: python, pandas, range

Primeiramente, eu tenho 2 dataframe com vários pontos de latitude e longitude:

`db_gas2['lat-long'] = db_gas2['latitude'].astype(str)+', '+db_gas2['longitude']`
`db_gas2`

`db_cidades3['lat-long'] = db_cidades3['latitude'].astype(str)+', '+db_cidades3['longitude']`
`db_cidades3.head()`

db_gas2 tem 37 linhas (que são locais)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

db_cidades3 tem 5.570 linhas (municipios do Brasil)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consegui criar isso em um simulador, porém não um for i range

`#teste se a variavel "ponto gás" iria funcionar`

`ponto_gas = 1`
`# range de 0 a 36`

`cidade_origem = 1050`
`# range de 0 a 5569`

`p1 = (db_cidades3.iloc[cidade_origem]['lat-long'])`

`p1_n = (db_cidades3.iloc[cidade_origem]['cidade'])`

`p2 = (db_gas2.iloc[ponto_gas]['lat-long'])`

`p2_n = (db_gas2.iloc[ponto_gas]['Ponto de entrega'])`

`print("A distância entre a cidade", p1_n, "e o ponto de entrega", p2_n, "é de:")`
`print(round((distance.distance(p1, p2).km),2),"km")`

A resposta vem correta
"A distância entre a cidade Teixeiras e o ponto de entrega TBG Bilac é de:
794.22 km"

Porém como fazer para cada municipio, calcula-se a distancia para os 37 linhas de gás.
Quero automaticamente, pegar a linha 1 da "db_cidades3" e calcular distancia para todas as linhas da "db_gas2", após isso pegar a linha 2 da "db_cidades3" e calcular distancia para todas as linhas da "db_gas2" ...

Conseguem me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Quando usamos `pandas` ou outras bibliotecas, temos a ideia de que elas resolvem tudo. O Python possui inúmeras bibliotecas que, ao trabalharem em conjunto, fazem dele uma super linguagem de programação.

Isto posto, vamos ao problema: Correlacionar todas as cidades com os pontos de entrega.

Para fazer isso, podemos pensar em um loop aninhado (*nested loop*) conforme abaixo:

```
for cidade in cidades:
    for pt_entrega in pontos_de_entrega:
        # seu codigo
```

**Nota**: No `pandas` seria algo como `for idx, row in df.iterrows():`

Isso, não é nem um pouco performático!!!

Vamos à solução

### Carregando bibliotecas

```
import io               # Esta servirá apenas para este teste
import itertools
import pandas as pd

from geopy import distance
```

### Definindo localidades

```
cidades1 = """
Código IBGE,Nome do Município,Código UF,UF,Estado,Capital,Latitude,Longitude
5200100,Abadiânia,52,GO,Goiás,0,-16.1970,-48.7057
3100203,Abaeté,31,MG,Minas Gerais,0,-19.1551,-45.4444
4314902,Porto Alegre,43,RS,Rio Grande do Sul,1,-30.0318,-51.2065
"""

cidades2 = """
Código IBGE,Nome do Município,Código UF,UF,Estado,Capital,Latitude,Longitude
5200050,Abadia de Goiás,52,GO,Goiás,0,-16.7573,-49.4412
3100104,Abadia dos Dourados,31,MG,Minas Gerais,0,-18.4831,-47.3916
"""
```

**Nota** uma vez que não tenho acesso à base, usei as localidades acima.

### Criando dataframes

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(cidades1), sep=",")
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(cidades2), sep=",")
```

### Transformando em lista de tuplas

```
campos = ['Nome do Município', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']

l1 = df1[campos].to_records(index=False)
l2 = df2[campos].to_records(index=False)
```

### Gerando o resultado

```
todos_para_todos = itertools.product(l1, l2)

for par_de_localidades in todos_para_todos:
    c1, lat1, lon1 = par_de_localidades[0]
    c2, lat2, lon2 = par_de_localidades[1]
    distancia = round((distance.distance((lat1, lon1), (lat2,lon2)).km),2)
    print(f"A distância entre a cidade {c1} e o ponto de entrega {c2} é de: {distancia}km")
```

**Nota**: Perceba que a variável `todos_para_todos` é o *pulo do gato*

### Resultado

```
A distância entre a cidade Abadiânia e o ponto de entrega Abadia de Goiás é de: 100.06km
A distância entre a cidade Abadiânia e o ponto de entrega Abadia dos Dourados é de: 289.0km
A distância entre a cidade Abaeté e o ponto de entrega Abadia de Goiás é de: 499.64km
A distância entre a cidade Abaeté e o ponto de entrega Abadia dos Dourados é de: 218.31km
A distância entre a cidade Porto Alegre e o ponto de entrega Abadia de Goiás é de: 1481.15km
A distância entre a cidade Porto Alegre e o ponto de entrega Abadia dos Dourados é de: 1336.25km
```

**Nota Final**: Não coloquei a saída dos dataframes, lista de tuplas e etc, para não deixar a resposta extensa.